# Ng-repeat com div

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma lista de informações.

Preciso que mostre 4 registros por linha, Tentei de varias formas, mas não consegui. Ele mostra todo os registros em uma linha.

```
<div flex layout="row" flex="100">
    <div layout="row" flex="25" layout-padding layout-align="center center" ng-repeat="redistribuir in marcarRedistribuir">
    {{redistribuir.numero}}
    </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é um problema necessariamente com o Angular mas eventualmente com elementos diferentes de HTML e como eles são desenhados na página. Para forçar as divs a estarem na mesma linha tens de usar CSS. `display: inline;` ou `float: left;` por exemplo. Alternativamente podes usar `span` em vez de `div` que por natureza das coisas é um elemento `inline`.

Sobre esses elementos e como manipulá-los:

```css
.na-mesma-linha {
  display: inline;
}

* {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>div A1</div>
<div>div A2</div>
<div class="na-mesma-linha">div B1</div>
<div class="na-mesma-linha">div B2</div><span>span 1</span>
```

#### E como os agrupar?

Aqui sim podes usar o Angular para inserir um elemento novo a encapsular esses elemento, mas podes também fazer isso com CSS:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

div:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
<div>div 5</div>
<div>div 6</div>
<div>div 7</div>
<div>div 8</div>
<div>div 9</div>
```

Se quiseres fazer com Angular, ou seja no HTML tens que reagrupar a array `marcarRedistribuir` para ter subarrays de 4 elementos. Exemplo:

```
marcarRedistribuir = marcarRedistribuir.reduce((arr, nr, i) => {
  const groupIndex = Math.floor(i / 4);
  if (!arr[groupIndex]) arr.push([]);
  arr[groupIndex].push(nr);
    return arr;
}, []);
```

e depois usar assim:

```html
<div flex layout="row" flex="100">
  <div layout="row" flex="25" layout-padding layout-align="center center" ng-repeat="group in marcarRedistribuir">
    <div ng-repeat="redistribuir in group">
      {{redistribuir.numero}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas como mostrar 4 por linha ?
Não entendi.

Comment: @Guilherme pois, estou no comboio e a ligação caiu :) Juntei um exemplo com float. Dá uma olhada. Vou juntar um exemplo com Angular também.

Comment: @Guilherme juntei um exemplo com lógica no Angular também.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou.

No caso testei com o angular e não com o css.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando as `diretivas` do `angular material`, portanto qualquer `css` de estruturação ele vai ignorar, seu código está correto, porém se existir alguma exceção na `flex="25"`, o próximo elemento vai para baixo (pelo que vi na imagem os números são extensos), caso ele não esteja indo para baixo, adicione a diretiva, `flex-wrap="wrap"` ou `flex-wrap="nowrap"`, ou seja, está certo, pois se o elemento transcende o container o angular não vai ter inteligência de recalcular os próximos. Se o conteúdo não transcender o container e o problema persistir, algum `padding` ou `margin` deve estar setado ou na `div` pai ou na filha.

Comment: Entendi o que vc disse. Imaginei. Mas a logica que o @Sergio falou funcionou.

Comment: Então maravilha hehe!